# if condition as part of GIT command

Tags: git, syntax

I need to check which submodule "using" specific origin url
I am trying to do something like this:

```
check_url="some_url"
git submodule foreach --recursive 'if [$(git remote get-url origin)==$check_url];then echo "YES" else echo "NO" fi'
```

For now I am getting an error message

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Whats is wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not only a semicolon in the `if` statement, but spaces around the brackets.  The beginning bracket `[` is actually a symlink to the `test` command, and as such, it needs to be separated from other commands, as does the ending bracket (`]`).

In addition, using `==` as a comparison is a bashism and is not portable to other shells, which means this won't work on most Debian or Ubuntu systems.  Finally, it's a best practice to put double quotes around your test arguments so that if they're empty or contain multiple words you don't get a parse error.

So it should look like this:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'if [ "$(git remote get-url origin)"  = "$check_url" ]; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi'
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the semicolon in the `if` statement:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'if [$(git remote get-url origin)==$check_url];then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi'
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the fi error but seems still something wrong with the syntax, receiving that error:
git-submodule: 1: eval: [https://gitserver/check==https://gitserver/check]: not found